# Howto do this with JOIN? Or is it generally possible?

Tags: mysql

I have a Table `pages` and two other ones called `page_options` and `page_option_values` which make optional options possible without modify the table layout.

The tables have the following structure (shortend):

```
pages:
 * page_id
 * name

page_options:
 * page_option_id
 * name

page_option_values:
 * page_id
 * page_option_id
 * value
```

Can I get a result from MySQL which selects all columns from `pages` and shows the name column from page_options `as virtual column` with value from `page_option_values`?

EDIT:

I have the following Query now - but don't now why it don't work?

```
SELECT
 n.page_id,
 n.page_name,
 a.column_name,
 v.value as a.column_name
FROM pages n
JOIN page_attribute_value v on v.page_id = n.page_id
JOIN page_attributes a on a.attribute_id = v.attribute_id
```

Comment: "Can i get a Result from MySQL which selects all Columns from pages and shows the name column from page_options "as virtual column" with value from page_option_values?" Yep using left joins. and dynamic SQL if you have an undeterministic number of name virtual columns

Comment: This is called "pivoting". If you don't know the column names ahead of time, you have to do it using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Barmar I got until this now:

"SELECT
    n.`navigation_item_id`,
    n.`parent_id`,
    n.`title`,
    n.`content_type`,
    n.`content_id`,
    n.`template`,
    n.`sort`,
    nio.`column_name`,
    niov.`value` as nio.`column_name`
FROM
 pages as n
JOIN page_item_options nio
 on nio.page_item_option_id = n.page_item_id
JOIN page_item_option_value niov
 on niov.page_item_option_id = nio.page_item_option_id"

But it doesn't work? :(

Comment: Please post a nicely formatted query in the question. It's very difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: @Barmar Updated Question with formated Query

Comment: @xQbert I have build a query but it doesn't work - can you have a look too?

Comment: You can't use `a.column_name` as an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started you need the left joins

You laid out the tables as Page_Options and page_option_values is this correct or is the page_attribute instead of option?

```
Select p.page_Id, p.name, po.page_option_Id, PO.name, POV.value
from pages P
LEFT JOIN page_option_Values POV
 on P.page_ID = POV.Page_Id
LEFT JOIN page_option PO
 on PO.Page_OptioN_ID = POV.Page_Option_ID
```